# invoke class that extends UiApplication and implements Runnable from main thread in Blackberry

Tags: java, blackberry, runnable

I have class that extends UiApplication and implements Runnable. I want to instantiate object of this class in one of my MainScreens. This first class is something similar to:

```
public class MyHelper extends UiApplication implements Runnable {

  public MyHelper() {
     //some code here
     new Thread(this).start();
  }

   public void run() {
    //another chunk here 
  }
}
```

In MainScreen I have in navigaionClick in the button:

```
MyHelper helper = new MyHelper();
```

Debugger stops at public MyHelper(). What should I do to properly instatiate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are few points

1.when declare a class extending UiApplication it basically creates and UI thread and starts the thread on app.enterEventDispatcher(); call. You don't need to implement Runnable interface for any reason.

```
public class MyHelper extends UiApplication {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            MyHelper app = new MyHelper ();
            app.enterEventDispatcher();
        }

       public MyHelper() {
         //some code here to push screen
      }
}
```

2.You can always implement runnable interface to your subclass of MainScreen

3.If you want to get the instance of UI Application, anytime in your screens you can always call

```
UiApplication.getUiApplication().getApplication()
```

This retries the current UIApplication instance.